# NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

hey am trying the get the user id when am creating payments but am getting that error above here is my controller

```
class Api::V1::PaymentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_payment, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

    # GET /payments or /payments.json
    def index
      @payments = Payment.all.order(created_at: :desc)
      render json: @payments
    end
  
    # GET /payments/1 or /payments/1.json
    def show
        if @payment
          render json: @payment
        else
          render json:@payment.errors  
      end
    end
   
    # GET /payments/new
    def new
      @payment = Payment.new
    end
  
    # GET /payments/1/edit
    def edit
    end
  
    # POST /payments or /payments.json
    def create
      @payment = Payment.new(payment_params.merge(tenant_id: current_tenant.id))
        if @payment.save
         render json: @payment
        else
         render json: @payment.errors
        end
    end
    
    # PATCH/PUT /payments/1 or /payments/1.json
    def update
      if @payment.update(payment_params)
        render json: {notice: "Payment was successfully updated." }
      else
        render json: { error: 'Unable to update payment' }
      end
    end
  
    # DELETE /payments/1 or /payments/1.json
    def destroy
      @payment.destroy
        render json: {notice: 'Payment succefully removed'}
    end
  
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_payment
      @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def payment_params
      params.require(:payment).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :address, :money_paid, :date, :nin_number, :tenant_id, :home_id)
    end
end
```

am used tenant as my user ,and am using devise to handle user login and logout

Answer (score 1):

it fails on current_tenant.id since current_tenant is nil and therefore the id cannot be accessed

try adding a private method

```
def set_tenant
  @tenant = User.find(params[:tenant_id)
end
```

that should be run on before_action to make sure that the current user has been set and then use @current_tenant.id in your method for create